# Vuetify code is not rendering in `v-html` vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to render vuetify v-image in v-html of vuejs
please see the code and attached image

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>2</v-card-title>
    <div v-html="test"></div>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "slot2",
  data() {
    return {
      test: `<v-img
              lazy-src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/10/6"
              max-height="150"
              max-width="250"
              src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/500/300"
            ></v-img>`,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

[image: Rendered Imge]

Comment: What do you expect this to do? `v-html` is used to render HTML, not Vue components. You can check your DOM but for me, it's totally legit that there is nothing rendered here. What is the endgoal here actually? You could use a render function or maybe even compile on the fly but it's not performant and probably overkill.

Comment: I think the problem here is not about inserting HTML code, because your code must be working. But the problem maybe is related to v-img. Try replace it by tag `<img>`. If it works, so you need to set up vuetify or v-img library. It worked here.

Answer (score 0):

As [`@kissu`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585/kissu) said, `v-html` is used to render HTML not a Vue component.

Also, I did not see any use case here to pass whole Vuetify component into HTML template. Instead you can bind the data dynamically (i.e image src) instead of passing/binding the whole Vuetify component.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    imgLazySrc: 'https://picsum.photos/id/11/10/6',
    imgSrc: 'https://picsum.photos/id/11/500/300'
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.9/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.9/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-img
           :lazy-src="imgLazySrc"
           max-height="150"
           max-width="250"
           :src="imgSrc"
           ></v-img>
  </v-app>
</div>
```